# JS regular expression for repeated unique character

Tags: javascript, regex, repeat

I am trying to determine whether a string contains exactly one given distinct character, repeated at least once. For example "bbbbb" should match but "ccMMcc" should not as it contains two different letters, c and m respectively. Presuming regular expressions would be the simplest way to do so, shame I suck at them, what will I need to match my string against?

Comment: Related and not an exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176684/find-if-the-string-contains-repeated-sequence-of-letters-javascript

Comment: What does "repeated at least once" mean? Does it mean that there must be at least two of those characters, e.g. "bb"? Or should a single character also match, e.g. "b"?

Comment: Also, do "characters" in question include newlines?

Comment: Not really interested in newlines, more standard keyboard characters; tab/indent and enter/linebreak aren't really part of my aim here :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a backreference:

```
^(.)\1+$
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex is:

```
\b(\w)\1*\b
```

that is:

- \b: word boundary
- (\w): the first char, group
- \1*: any number of repetition of the first char

Comment: This will match `-a-` or even `A`

Answer (score 1):

`"tttt".match(/^(.)\1*$/)` returns `["tttt","t"]` but `"test".match(/^(.)\1*$/)` returns `null`

Comment: the asterisk `*` means 0 or more occurrences so this regex will match single character for example `"a"`

Comment: It should be asterisk otherwise won't match single char. Is "repeated at least once" means the string must contain at least two chars?

Comment: "repeated at least once" means that the string should contain the character more than once, so you need to replace the asterisk with a plus sign(`+`)