# JavaScript Regular Expression Rule for repeated characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a RegEx rule to find side-to-side digits in a number. For example given an array of:

```
const nums = [1, 2, 33, 4, 22, 5, 66, 112];
```

I want to remove the digits `[33, 22, 66, 112]` from the array because they have repeated digits.

I tried the `/[0-9/{2}` but this seems to not work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176684/how-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-a-sequence-of-repeated-letters or

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`  with regex pattern ( which uses capturing group and back reference )

- `[0-9]{2}` -  Means match any digit from 0 to 9 two times which doesn't guaranty repeated digits
- `([0-9])\1`

  - `([0-9])` - Means match digit 0 to 9 ( captured group 1 )
  - `\1` - should match the same value as the captured group 1

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 33, 4, 22, 5, 66, 112];

let nonRepeated = nums.filter(num => !/([0-9])\1/.test(""+num)) 

// can replace with !/([0-9])\1/.test(num) because it implicit coerce to string

console.log(nonRepeated)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So if I were supposed to store this rule in a variable and use it as a Boolean for a condition, can I directly save it as: 

const test = /([0-9])\1/;

Comment: @ZakiSediqyar yes, `const test = /([0-9])\1/` will also work

Comment: no `""+num` necessary, because the value is converted to string.

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for info didn't knew about implicit conversion to string for `test`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\1` backreference like so:

```
/(\d)\1+/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter and includes

```
const nums = [1, 2, 33, 4, 22, 5, 66, 112];

result = nums.filter(v => ![33, 22, 66, 112].includes(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

the shortest approach is just to check if a same character is followed by itselft. No need for checking dor digits, because the value contains only digits or a dot (or `E` or space). The last occurs only once.

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 33, 4, 22, 5, 66, 112],
    nonRepeated = nums.filter(v => !/(.)\1/.test(v));

console.log(nonRepeated);
```